# Error using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, rubygems, adapter

I installed activerecord-sqlserver-adapter such that it appears in my local gems.
Running the command...

```
rails generate scaffold Tablename fieldname:fieldtype
```

returns an error (as below).  I've rails 1.9.2 installed.  Any guidance or assistance would be much appreciated.  Thanks

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the sqlserver adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter) (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:166:in `pluralize_table_names?'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:114:in `table_name'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb:17:in `create_migration_file'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `block in invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `map'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:238:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:281:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/shell.rb:74:in `with_padding'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:270:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:150:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `block in invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `map'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:238:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-.2.8/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (3.2.8, 3.1.0, 2.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.8, 3.1.0, 2.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.9, 3.2.8, 3.1.0)
activerecord (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.10, 3.1.7)
activeresource (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
activesupport (3.2.9, 3.2.8, 3.1.0, 2.2.3)
ansi (1.4.3, 1.3.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2, 2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2, 3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0, 1.1.2)
columnize (0.3.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0, 1.2.9)
ffi (1.1.5)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4, 2.1.3, 1.0.14)
json (1.7.5, 1.6.1)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.4.4, 2.3.0)
mime-types (1.19, 1.16)
minitest (4.1.0, 3.5.0, 3.4.0, 1.6.0)
multi_json (1.4.0, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.0.3)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.2)
rack (1.4.1, 1.3.4)
rack-cache (1.2, 1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
railties (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
rake (10.0.2, 10.0.1, 0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.12, 3.10, 2.5.8)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
sass (3.2.3, 3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.2.5, 3.1.4)
sprockets (2.1.3, 2.0.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32, 1.3.4 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.16.0, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
tmail (1.2.7.1)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.11, 1.4.10)
turn (0.9.6, 0.8.3)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.30)
uglifier (1.3.0, 1.0.3)
win32-sound (0.5.0)
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rails generate scaffold tablename fieldname:fieldtype` ?

Comment: I have now.  Same error.  Must be something to do with gem versions/locations but I can't see what/where this is wrong. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this.  To fix I uninstalled 2 conflicting versions of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, installed ruby-odbc gem, installed activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, tweaked the gemfile to reflect correct versions then ran bundle update, then bundle install and lastly the rails generate scaffold... command.

Answer (score 0):

Is the gem listed in your `Gemfile`?

Add to your gemfile ([gem manual](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#installation))

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.1.0'
```

and run `bundle install` again

Comment: I added the lines above to the site gemfile and ran bundle install.  Some improvement but the main error still present - it seems rails can't find activerecod-sqlserver-adapter